# Template function to discern smart_pointer from other container

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, overloading, template-templates

Consider the following template functions:

```
template <class T>
const T* DoSomething(const T& t)
{
    auto& id = typeid(T);
    cout << "Type is " << id.name() << ", and we have a ";
    cout << "ref of one\n";
    return &t;
}

template <class T>
T* DoSomething(T* t)
{
    auto& id = typeid(T);
    cout << "Type is " << id.name() << ", and we have a ";
    cout << "pointer to one \n";
    return t;
}

template <class T, template <class> class container>
T* DoSomething(const container<T>& t)
{
    auto& type_id = typeid(T);
    auto& container_id = typeid(container<T>);
    cout << "Type is " << type_id.name() << ", and we have a ";
    cout << container_id.name() << "of one\n";
    return t.get();
}

template <class T, template <class,class> class container, template <class> class deleter = default_delete>
T* DoSomething(const container<T, deleter<T>>& t)
{
    auto& type_id = typeid(T);
    auto& container_id = typeid(container<T,deleter<T>>);
    cout << "Type is " << type_id.name() << ", and we have a ";
    cout << container_id.name() << "of one\n";
    return t.get();
}
```

The goal is to be able to pass to them either a plain reference, pointer, or smart pointer, and use overloading and template specilization in order for the correct function to be called. The following driving code works as expected:

```
char r('r');
DoSomething(r);  
DoSomething(&r);
shared_ptr<char> s(new char ('s'));
unique_ptr<char> u(new char ('u'));
DoSomething(s);
DoSomething(u);
```

However, consider what happens if we try this:

```
vector<int> v {1,2};
DoSomething(v);
```

Now, we we get a compile error. The version of DoSomething that the compiler decides to use is the 4th one. Inside this, we reference a function get(), which vector does not have. If the compiler were to somehow pick the 1st defintion of DoSomething, it would compile fine, and work as I intend.

So can I restrict the 3rd and 4th specializations to only be matched when the template template parameter contains a get() method? Is there a way I can get this to happen, perhaps using traits, SFINAE, or some other more advanced template technique?

Comment: SFINAE is the typical way to go here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The version of DoSomething that the compiler decides to use is the 4th one.

Because `std::vector<T, std::allocator<T>>` is an exact match for the template parameter `container` and `std::allocator<T>` is an exact match for the template parameter `deleter`, and `const container<T, deleter<T>>&` is more specialized than `const T&` so the 4th overload is chosen as the best match by the partial ordering rules for function templates.

> So can I restrict the 3rd and 4th specializations to only be matched when the template template parameter contains a get() method?

Yes, you can tell the compiler that the function returns whatever `t.get()` returns:

```
template <class T, template <class> class container>
auto DoSomething(const container<T>& t) -> decltype(t.get())
{
    auto& type_id = typeid(T);
    auto& container_id = typeid(container<T>);
    cout << "Type is " << type_id.name() << ", and we have a ";
    cout << container_id.name() << "of one\n";
    return t.get();
}
```

If `t.get()` is not a valid expression then template argument deduction fails, because the argument `T` cannot be substituted into the function signature successfully, and so the function will not be a viable overload, and the 1st overload will be used instead.

Comment: That's a very clever way for SFINAE. I want to add a note: If `t` is supposed to also have another method available (in general, if the method which is required != the return expression), let's say `set(int)`, we can write `-> decltype(t.set(std::declval<int>()), t.get())`.

Comment: That's really cool. I was expecting to have to do something a lot more complicated than this. Thanks.

Comment: Actually, the example baked up for SO is not quite what I need. In my code there is actually no return type from the DoSomething functions there are all void, so I can't do exactly what you describe. I'm trying what leemes suggests, with -> decltype(t.get(),void) but this does not compile

Comment: It should be `decltype(t.get(), void())` or `decltype(t.get(), (void)0)`, because `void` is a type not an expression, and `decltype` needs an expression as its operand.  Either `void()` or `(void)0` is an expression of type `void`.

Answer (score 2):

The OP code has a flaw when a std::unique_ptr with a custom deleter is used:

```
struct Deleter {
    void operator()(char*) const {}
};

unique_ptr<char, Deleter> u(new char ('u'), Deleter());
DoSomething(u) // The first is applied.
```

Using duck typing via SFINAE is troublesome.

```
template <typename T, typename U>
struct X { 
    // Is this a get like a get of a smart pointer !?  
    T* get();
}
```

I recommend the solution of user1095108.

Comment: Yes, you point out a valid weakness of the scheme. There is definitely some merit in using explicit overloads for shared_ptr and unique_ptr.

Comment: The problem with custom deleters is easily solved by changing the 4th overload to accept any deleter, not just ones matching `template<class> class deleter`, but that might cause other problems, and your main point is a good one

Answer (score 1):

I'd try this:

```
template <typename>
struct is_smart : ::std::false_type
{
};

template <typename T>
struct is_smart<::std::shared_ptr<T> > : ::std::true_type
{
};
```

Use like this:

```
::std::cout << is_smart<container<T> >{} << ::std::endl;
```

But I'd rather override like this:

```
template <class T>
T* DoSomething(const ::std::shared_ptr<T>& t)
{
}
```

for every container and smart pointer type you intend to support.

Comment: Thanks for the response - any tips on how to intgrate this with me code?

Comment: How does writing a `bool` to a stream help call the right overload?

Comment: It helps to see `1` and `0` for different `T`s.